# jQuery - slideToggle keep open until closed

Tags: jquery

I'm creating af slide panel for the userOptions for my members. It's working nicely with:

```
//Login panel, slideUp when clicked <-> slideDown
$('#loginPanel').click(function(){
    $('#userNav').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

But I would like the panel to stay open when you refresh the page or go to another page on the website. If the user close the panel it has to stay closed, untill opened again etc.

Is this possible?

*** Add to answer ***

For the instant "slide" i just added 1 to the speed:

```
$('#div').slideToggle(1);
```

and same for the other ones in the $.cookie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [$.cookie()](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin to set and remember the current state of the panel and load it accordingly on page refresh / change.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Open / Close Panel According to Cookie //    
    if ($.cookie('panel') == 'open'){    
        $('#userNav').slideDown('fast'); // Show on Page Load / Refresh with Animation
        $('#userNav').show(); // Show on Page Load / Refresh without Animation
    } else {
        $('#userNav').slideUp('fast'); // Hide on Page Load / Refresh with Animation
        $('#userNav').hide(); // Hide on Page Load / Refresh without Animation
    }

    // Toggle Panel and Set Cookie //
    $('#loginPanel').click(function(){        
        $('#userNav').slideToggle('fast', function(){
            if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
                $.cookie('panel', 'closed');
            } else {
                $.cookie('panel', 'open');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

EDIT: Here's fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK/

You can use the fiddle and refresh the page to see the cookies work.

I hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for [cookie monster](http://www.google.com/search?q=cookie+monster&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1280&bih=907&sei=%20AgmrTszkI8vAtgeihKTdDg)

Comment: I think I'm doing somehting wrong. Or maybe I just need to add something to the question. I'm having af DIV which is #loginPanel - when you click this, it has to slideDown #userNav. Right now nothing happens.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery $.cookie() plugin? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: @dSquared oh, the $.cookie() plugin isn't standard for the google 1.6 (i think) link? And I'm receiving no errors

Comment: My document looks exactly like the fiddle. :-s

Comment: @Kolind Have you downloaded and included the $.cookie plugin from the link in the answer? It is a plugin and needs to be included along with the jQuery Framework.

Comment: @dSquared Hi again. I fell a sleep yesterday ;-) But it works now, I had to include the jquery cookie library. :-) Works awesome. I'm just wondering a think. Can't you make it not to slide down on refreshed/changed page, but just to be there instantly?

Comment: @Kolind Sure; take a look at the edited answer. You would use $.show or $.hide instead of $.slideDown and $.slideUp. Give it a try =)

Comment: @dSquared Hey. I've tried that already, and it creates some weird fast slideIn from the left with the text in the slided div. Looks really really bad. :-(

Comment: @dSquared +1 for the clarity in your code. However your [code works in jsFiddle, I modified accordig to my needs](http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK/714/). Yet it doesn't seem to work in the aspx page. This particular div has a panel and it carries the gridview. Gridview also has a another jquery plug-in code which is used to fixed the header and make it scrollable. Could this be some issue for toggle to not work?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah put the info in a cookie, if the user click the userOption you put the info in the cookie, when you load the page you look in the cookie if the userOption is open.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to use something like a URL hash, or better yet, cookies to write the state to the browser.

Something like the following (with your modifications to use slideToggle) should point you in the right direction: http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/cookies-with-jquery-designing-collapsible-layouts/