# jQuery toggle not staying open when page refreshes

Tags: jquery, cookies, plugins, toggle

Having a problem that a collapsible menu in a fixed sidebar is not staying open when the links are clicked (or when the page simply refreshes).

I used the suggestions based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934139/jquery-slidetoggle-keep-open-untill-closed) about using a cookie to store the div's state but it's not working (toggle state is still not persisting).

I added a link to the plugin (AFTER my jQuery src link):

```
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the toggle state still doesn't stay, even live on a .com website.

```
if ($.cookie('div') == 'open'){
    $('#the_more_div').slideDown('slow');
} else {
    $('#the_more_div').slideUp('slow');
}

$('#hamburger').click(function(){
    $('#the_more_div').slideToggle('slow', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
            $.cookie('div', 'closed');
        } else {
            $.cookie('div', 'open');
        }
    }); 
});
```

The toggle works just fine but why wouldn't the_more_div stay open when different links are clicked inside it (or on page refresh).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've tested it on jsfiddle and it's working fine. [jsfiddle.net/UJDsh/](http://jsfiddle.net/UJDsh/). Have you checked it on other browser, and are you loading jquery first before the jquery.cookie plugin?

Comment: Amazing, @MarkS because it simply does not function correctly online. Tried Chrome & Firefox. You can look at it live [here](http://www.nicocrisafulli.com) - in the sidebar. Most definitely loading jquery first.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was an unrelated conflict. The above code *does* in fact work to install a cookie to make the div status persist.