# Add cookies to toggle sidebar

Tags: javascript, cookies, toggle, sidebar

I have a toggling sidebar on my side, and now I want to use cookies to make it remember what state it's at. This has been brought up a lot before, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works with my code. (Or maybe it does, but I'm really new at this, I could just have used it wrong.)

```
var main = function() {
    $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);

        $('body').animate({
            left: "240px"
        }, 200);
    });

    $('.icon-close').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "-240px"
        }, 200);

        $('body').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);

    });
};
```

I looked into [this ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984162/jquery-toggle-not-staying-open-when-page-refreshes), it seems to be what I'm looking for, but the codes where so different I didn't get it to work. Same with [enter link description here](http://devheart.org/articles/jquery-collapsible-sidebar-layout/) Viktor's helpful setup here - would it be easier to just redo the code with something more "standard"? Or can I set up an if command for both the menu and the body?

Grateful for all tips. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and include [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), and use it as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);

        $('body').animate({
            left: "240px"
        }, 200);

        Cookies.set('menu-state', 'open');
    });

    $('.icon-close').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "-240px"
        }, 200);

        $('body').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);

        Cookies.set('menu-state', 'closed');
    });

    // Open menu (without animation) if it was open last time
    if (Cookies.get('menu-state') === 'open') {
        $('.menu').css({
            left: "0px"
        });

        $('body').css({
            left: "240px"
        });
    } else {
        $('.menu').css({
            left: "-240px"
        });

        $('body').css({
            left: "0px"
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Trincot! However, doing this - your code, and before that
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myurl/path/js.cookie.js"> made the sidebar freeze in open position. The result is the same if I reverse the if open. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: I added an else block at the bottom. Could you check if that resolves the issue?

Comment: Nope, same thing. This was also the same issue I ran into when I tried to use the code from devheart - is it my sourcing that's wrong? Does any of the other files but the js.cookie one need to be uploaded?

Thank you for all help so far, it's very appreciated!