# Cookies lagging

Tags: javascript, cookies, sidebar, lag

I recently asked about how to add cookies to a sidebar menu, and got help by amazing Trincot, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462473/add-cookies-to-toggle-sidebar). Found and edited another code to get that to work, now the problem with that code is that it the cookies lag - if you close the sidebar and move to another page, it shows up for a second, then disappears, and considering the entire site's content moves with it, this is incredibly annoying. I think I found a similar question while looking for solution to my previous problem, but I can't remember what I searched for, and haven't been able to re-locate it. I *think* the fault is with the repetition of the code, but I need to be able to open and close it from two places. Any ideas, anyone?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://yourjavascript.com/1211131136/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/**code written by kismet of RPG-Directory.com**/


$(function(){
var website = 'SKY';
var cookie1 = website+'cbox';


if($.cookie(cookie1) === 'on' ||
$.cookie(cookie1) === null){
$('.menu').animate({
left: "-240px"
}, 200);

$('body').animate({
left: "0px"
}, 200); }

else {
$('.menu').animate({
left: "0px"
}, 200);

$('body').animate({
left: "240px"
}, 200); }


$('.icon-close').click(function(){

$.cookie(cookie1, 'on');

$('.menu').animate({
left: "-240px"
}, 200);

$('body').animate({
left: "0px"
}, 200);

});


$('.icon-menu').click(function(){

if($.cookie(cookie1) === 'on' ||
$.cookie(cookie1) === null){

$.cookie(cookie1, 'off');

$('.menu').animate({
left: "0px"
}, 200);

$('body').animate({
left: "240px"
}, 200); }

else {

$.cookie(cookie1, 'on');

$('.menu').animate({
left: "-240px"
}, 200);

$('body').animate({
left: "0px"
}, 200); }

});
});
</script>
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Slimmed the code down, and removed some unnecessary elements, but despite putting hours into this I'm no closer to a solution

Comment: What is the “default” status of the sidebar on page load, before your script checks the cookie value? There likely is no “cookie lag” – if the sidebar is visible when the page loads, and only then gets hidden by your script when loading is completely finished, then that would be the “lag” you’re seeing.

Comment: If you don’t want any animation of the sidebar when switching to the next page, then you should write a piece of code that runs way earlier, and adds a class to the `html` element depending on the cookie value – and then in your CSS set up rules that hide/show the sidebar based on that class.