# jQuery toggle state changes upon refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I looked through some older questions and learnt that to solve this issue I need to implement cookies and somehow remember the states. Being new to jquery, it is turning out to be a little tricky for me to implement this.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.trthJobStatus caption').click(function() {
    $('.trthJobStatus th,.trthJobStatus td').slideToggle('1000');

});
});
```

Anyone knows how I can use cookies to remember the state and avoid my toggle state to change when page is refreshed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look in to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934139/jquery-slidetoggle-keep-open-until-closed , same question which is already answered. Possible duplicate

Comment: @loganSarav - Tried the solution but didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of using localStorage over cookies, particularly if you have an application that needs to be device agnostic. Note that the code below does not reset the localStorage var when it's no longer needed.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      if(localStorage['trthJobStatus']){
        $('.trthJobStatus th,.trthJobStatus td').slideToggle('1000');
      }
      $('.trthJobStatus caption').click(function() {
        localStorage['trthJobStatus'] = true;
        $('.trthJobStatus th,.trthJobStatus td').slideToggle('1000');
      });
    });
```

EDIT: Here is the solution that worked!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
if(window.localStorage.getItem('trthJobStatus') === 'true'){ 
  $('.trthJobStatus th,.trthJobStatus td').slideUp('1000'); } 
  $('.trthJobStatus caption').click(function(){
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('trthJobStatus') === 'true'){   window.localStorage.setItem('trthJobStatus', 'false');                                                    }else{
       window.localStorage.setItem('trthJobStatus', 'true'); 
       } 
      console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('trthJobStatus'));
    $('.trthJobStatus th,.trthJobStatus td').slideToggle('1000'); });

});
```

Comment: I tried the code but now the table is not toggling at all.

Comment: Yes, of course. I am sorry about that; we'll have to check the state of the localStorage variable and toggle it with the mouse click. `localStorage['trthJobStatus'] = localStorage['trthJobStatus'] ? false : true;`

Comment: Tried this and still doesn't work:

`if(localStorage['trthJobStatus']){
  $('.trthJobStatus th,.trthJobStatus td').slideToggle('1000');
    }
    $('.trthJobStatus caption').click(function() {
  localStorage['trthJobStatus'] = localStorage['trthJobStatus'] ? false : true;;
        $('.trthJobStatus th,.trthJobStatus td').slideToggle('1000');
    });`

Comment: I moved around the code a bit. It toggles now but the default state is collapsed now when i refresh the page :(

Comment: Okay, I just figured this out. localStorage only works with strings. http://jsbin.com/dojanokolo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!! I will need to read up more on local storage to fully understand how it works :)

Comment: You're very welcome. There is also sessionStorage which stores values only for the session. I got the impression you wanted the table visibility to persist but if you don't it would be a better option as it wouldn't live in a user's cache as long. Here's a link I found about localStorage; MDN also has useful information. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/