# How to set a cookie for a certain element by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I have a page with multiple div and in each div I have a Form with the class of .sendCommentForm..

The multiple divs are printed in the page because of PHP loop, so that's why I have multiple forms in the same page.

I don't want to show the forms directly, the user will click on a button, then the form will slideToggle by jQuery.

I needed to keep the form as slidToggled when the page gets refreshed (the form should slideDown, if it was slide down before the page refreshed)

I have searched and found cookies by jQuery. and It's working fine, but the problem is that all of the form with that same class name are getting slideDown, and I want only one form (or the specific forms) that were in slideDown state before page refresh.

This topic helped me to reach where I'm:
[jQuery - slideToggle keep open until closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934139/jquery-slidetoggle-keep-open-until-closed)

The code I have (HTML):

```
<div class="options text-center"></a>
    <button class="btn btn-info sendComment">
        Comment
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="sendCommentForm">
    <form action="mypage" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="subject" class="form-control">
        <button type="submit"></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

jQuery:-

```
// Open / Close Panel According to Cookie //    
if($.cookie('comForm') == 'open') {
    $('.sendCommentForm').slideDown('fast');
} else {
    $('.sendCommentForm').slideUp('fast');
}

// Toggle Panel and Set Cookie //
$('.sendComment').click(function() {
    var theForm = $(this).parent().next('.sendCommentForm');
    theForm.slideToggle('fast', function() {
        if($(this).is(':hidden')) {
            $.cookie('comForm', 'closed');
        } else {
            $.cookie('comForm', 'open');
        }
    });
});
```

Can I change the element : $('.sendCommentForm') to be $(this) so it can identify the same form that was in slideDown state...
I have tried that and its not working!!

I have a headache from this problem, and I'm so confused.

Thank you for helping..

Comment: Where do you want to make that change? `$(this)` is only meaningful inside a function that binds the context to a specific element. Like in an event handler `$(this)` is the event target.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a unquie identifier such as ID or data attribute and maybe store a comma separated list in cookie of the ids.

It would be preferential to use browser session, as cookies get sent to the server for every request on the domain in which the cookie was set. Depending on your audience check the browser support for browser session or local storage to see if this is something you could make use of.

Comment: How I am going to give unique ID to each form and I have only one form in the code but its being duplicated by PHP though loop?  What should I do please? I'm little bit confused.

Comment: If for example you are pull these comments from a database, I would assume that the comment has some kind of identifier or primary key. As well as pulling out the comment, which you must be iterating over in a loop, also have the ID of the comment available in the loop, do you have the example of the PHP loop?

Comment: Do you have the php code that is iterating through the comments?

Comment: It's okay, I already forgot about this problem because its extremely hard to solve and I hate programming..

Thanks so much for replying to my question..

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each form a different ID. In the cookie, save an object whose keys are the IDs, and values are the open/closed states.

```
$('.sendComment').click(function() {
    var theForm = $(this).parent().next('.sendCommentForm');
    theForm.slideToggle('fast', function() {
    var state = {};
    $('.sendCommentForm').each(function() {
      state[this.id] = $(this).is(':visible');
    });
    $.cookie('comForm', state);
  });
});
```

Then when the page loads, get the cookie and display each form based on the value from the object.

```
var comformState = $.cookie('comForm');
if (comformState) {
    $.each(comformState, function(id, visible) {
        $('#' + id).parent().next('.sendCommentForm')[visible ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']('fast');
    });
}
```

Comment: How I am going to give unique ID to each form and I have only one form in the code but its being duplicated by PHP though loop?  What should I do please? I'm little bit confused.

Comment: Increment a variable in the loop, and include that variable in the IDs.